# Is there a way to call method when first item is picked in React Native Picker?

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

**EDIT**

`functionToRedirect(itemValue)` is a function that gets called when an item in the picker is selected and it redirects to a new screen prepopulating some values in the screen based on `'itemValue'`.

However, `functionToRedirect(itemValue)` is not being called when the same value is selected which I assume is because the value didn't change and thus `onValueChange()` will not be fired.

Is there a way for me to call the `functionToRedirect(itemValue)` even when the value didn't change(i.e when the initial value is selected) to try and redirect to the new screen?

```
<Picker
  style={styles.picker}
  itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
  mode={"dialog"}
  selectedValue={this.props.value}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
    functionToRedirect(itemValue);
  }
}>
  {this.state.pickerItems}
</Picker>
```

Comment: I dont think its possible to listen for onValueChange without a value is actually changed/picked. And i don't think onvalueChange is called when Picker component is initialized.

Comment: I don't think Picker support any such props. [https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker.html]. It will be called only after you make change on default value.

Comment: Is there a way then for me to have a Picker like component that maybe has an onSelect method that gets called whenever an item is selected from the list even if the it's the same as what value was before?

Comment: Can you add more code and be more clear about what you need to apply?

Comment: @Parthshrivastav I tried to clarify the question. hope it makes more sense.

Comment: If it works you can try adding a default picker option as the first choice eg. ```Select option``` to avoid having this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to pass selectedValue null such that the first displayed option in the dropdown is the dropdown title.

The solution looks like below

```
<Picker
  style={styles.picker}
  itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
  mode={"dialog"}
  selectedValue={null}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
    this.props.onChange(itemValue)
  }}
>
  {this.state.pickerItems}
</Picker>
```

which shows the picker title as the initial value of the dropdown as shown below
[image: image of dropdown showing title instead of first element]

Answer (score 1):

How about using a custom picker? [Nativebase](https://nativebase.io/), a custom implementation of ReactNative UI components can give you a customised flavour of the components.
They have implemented [Picker](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref) using RN Picker as a wrapper around flatlist of items opened in a modal window through which you can select items accordingly.

Comment: I am working on a work project and thus I have to specifically use ReactNative components. I will have a look at Nativebase though for future side projects.

Comment: It’s okay if you go through nativebase in your work project also. All dependencies are managed through npm package manager including ReactNative. Which means NPM is the provider of all packages so I don’t think so it could create an issue in your case.

Comment: Also, if you still want to get sticked with RN components then you can also create a custom Picker of your own and include it as a component. You can take reference from NativeBase or any other UI implementer out there.